# Use replicate() on a range of columns and apply stats to the results

Tags: r

I've got a cross-tab of frequencies i.e. for column A01 there are 6485 counts of 13 CAGs, 35 counts of 14 CAGs etc.
I've managed to convert it into long data for column A01, which I can then use to work out mean and sd. However, I've got n columns, and I'm not sure how to apply this function to all columns.

```
data <- data.frame(CAG = c(13, 14, 15), A01 = c(6485,35,132), A02 = c(0,42,56))
cag = rep(data$CAG, data$A01)
mean <- mean(cag)
stdef <- sd(cag)
```

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `sapply`? `sapply(data, function(x) c(mean=mean(x), sd=sd(x)))`. Also, its better to use unique names for your objects. `data` also refers to a function in R.

Comment: It looks like what you are trying to do is the weighted mean/SD. Is that correct? By "apply[ing] this function to all columns" do you mean you want to use `A01` as weights, `A02` as weights, etc?

Answer (score 0):

```
L = list()

for (i in 1:ncol(data)){
  tmp = rep(data[i, 1], data[i, 2])
  mean = mean(tmp)
  stdef = sd(tmp)
  L[[i]] = cbind(mean, stdef)
}
Mx = do.call(rbind, L)
Mx
```